# Capture text using only a starting marker and starting marker appears multiple times in a line

Tags: ruby, regex

Given this text:

```
fluid * capable of flowing freely like water
* having or showing a smooth and easy style

liquid * shining and clear * clear, smooth, and pleasant in sound
```

I need to be able to capture these parts separately

1. `capable of flowing freely like water`
2. `having or showing a smooth and easy style`
3. `shining and clear`
4. `clear, smooth, and pleasant in sound`

Using this regex: `/\*(.*)/`

Resulted to:

1. `capable of flowing freely like water`
2. `having or showing a smooth and easy style`
3. `shining and clear * clear, smooth, and pleasant in sound`

Is it possible to accomplish this task without introducing a closing tag?

Comment: Can you just do this? \*([^*]*)

Comment: ^ quite close. tested it in rubular and it captures "\n liquid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex - `\*(.*)` - matches a literal asterisk and then matches 0 or more characters (as many as possible) other than a newline. In most cases, `.*` matches the rest of the line, with or without other asterisks.

All you need is `scan` with `\*([^*\n]*)` regex (where the negated character class `[^*\n]` limits the match to the next asterisk or a newline):

```
s.scan(/\*([^*\n]*)/)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ozEx4A)

Note that `scan` will only return captured texts if capture groups are defined in the regular expression. We define it as `([^*\n])` which matches any character but a newline and an asterisk. `\*` matches a literal asterisk, and `*` quantifier tells the regex engine to match the preceding subpattern 0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by writing

```
str.gsub(/\n\n.*?\s/,'').gsub("\n",'').split('*').drop(1)
```

it gives this

```
[" capable of flowing freely like water", " having or showing a smooth and easy style", " shining and clear ", " clear, smooth, and pleasant in sound"]
```

to remove the whitespaces from the begining and the end of each line

```
str.gsub(/\n\n.*?\s/,'').gsub("\n",'').split('*').drop(1).map(&:lstrip)
```

Comment: Used it in irb and it gave me: [" capable of flowing freely like water\n", " having or showing a smooth and easy style\n\nliquid ", " shining and clear ", " clear, smooth, and pleasant in sound"]. LIQUID was included. still, thanks! i was too focused on regex to solve the problem. your answer gave a needed jump for my thinking.